# Ubuntu 16.04, Nvidia Geforce GT 610 getting nvidia drivers to work

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, graphics, hdmi

I just installed 16.04 (gnome) on my machine and I have a nvidia geforce GT610 graphics card in my machine. I'm connected with hdmi to my tv for display and sound. At first I had no sound (through hdmi), so after a lot of reading I ended up installing nvidia drivers.

**Attemp1**:
I tried to install through ubuntu-drivers-common package the right drivers. First I selected a few wrong ones (my mistake) but than I installed the 370 driver. Than it worked! I had a propper visual and sound!. However the next day when I booted again, I got this screen (sorry for the bad quality) :

[image]

It seems to hang when starting up processes. So after removing the nvidia drivers, everything was back to normal but still no sound.

**Attemp2**
I installed/used the lightdm display manager instead of gdm. I got through the login screen, but I wasn't able to to login with my account (error: couldn't create a session). I could however login with a guest account and my sound was working again. But I rather stick with gdm if I can.. So after trying some other stuff I ruined the whole installation and I did a fresh install..

**Attemp3**
I download the drivers from nvidia.com and run the .run file. During boot I finally get again that ubuntu loading splash screen with the . . . . flashing. But afterwards my screen becomes black and flashes every 5 seconds from black to a little less black..

So after a few days, I'm getting a bit frustrated, so some help would be nice :)

Comment: The low end GT610 is quite easy to use and doesn't even require the latest drivers. Your problem is somewhere else. Most likely too much "attempts". In a properly installed 16.04 the best and tested driver can be easily installed at Additional drivers.

Comment: I had it working on 14.10, but now it doesn't seem to so easy :(. I already reinstalled once between attemp 2 and 3 (so 2 fresh install already) but you comment made me do the third fresh install and use that gui tool additional drivers. It picked the 340 driver and now I again have a black screen during bootup :(

Comment: @CelticWarrior: Can you convert your comment into an answer? so I can mark it as the answer. I first installed the 370 driver instead of 340 (typo) now installed the 340 driver and it all started to work :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The low end GT610 is quite easy to use and doesn't even require the latest drivers. Your problem is somewhere else. Too much "attempts" installing graphics drivers without properly cleaning the system of all remains of the version in use prior to try a new one can have all sorts of undesired effects.

In a properly installed 16.04 the best and tested driver can be easily installed at Additional Drivers. The long term support 340.xx seems to give the optimal result for your card.